# Crawling itunes.apple.com

Tags: curl, app-store

I am trying to crawl the apple itunes website. I am getting output in binary format. 
For example

curl -A "mozilla/5.0"  http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-far-islands-by-john-buchan/id327765949?mt=8

returns binary.

Can anybody please tell me what i am missing?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "binary format"?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting binary back because the page you cited isn't returning HTML/XML, it's returning an Apple WebObject. From `wget`:

```
wget http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-far-islands-by-john-buchan/id327765949?mt=8
--2010-08-03 12:38:14--  http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-far-islands-by-john-buchan/id327765949?mt=8
Resolving itunes.apple.com... 17.250.237.16
Connecting to itunes.apple.com|17.250.237.16|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 Apple WebObjects
Length: 22900 (22K) [text/html]
Saving to: `id327765949?mt=8'

100%[======================================>] 22,900      --.-K/s   in 0.05s   

2010-08-03 12:38:14 (440 KB/s) - `id327765949?mt=8' saved [22900/22900]
```

See the [good old Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebObjects) for more info, but if you want to crawl it, you may need to use something that simulates a browser and thus can interpret it - maybe [watir](http://watir.com/) would work.

Comment: Your wget command indicates that it's returning text/html.

I just ran curl on my machine like the OP and got HTML:
https://gist.github.com/2047126